# Parsing webpage with powershell

Tags: html, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to parse the following webpage:

`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647642.aspx`

For this line:

`Offline catalog (Wsusscn2.cab). This is the offline catalog file. Download it from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76054.`

So that I can download the file linked there.

However, whenever I do the following:

```
$url = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76054
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$result.content | select-string "Wsusscn2.cab"
```

This just returns all the content on the page.  How can I parse for just the link?

Comment: [This Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859843/grab-image-links-from-html-website-using-powershell) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I dont think it is a duplicate as the key is to désactivate redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to disable redirection :

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url -UseBasicParsing -MaximumRedirection 0 -ea silentlycontinue 
$result.links.href
```

Answer (score -3):

For the links:

```
$url = 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647642.aspx'
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$r.links
```

For the download:

```
$url = 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76054'
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile 'c:\Wsusscn2.cab'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is trying to *return* a string of `"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76054"` from the contents of `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647642.aspx`.